# Select parent node by child's Innertext XMLDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Hello i am trying to retrieve node by its innertext. I want to get Product node of which child text should match input

```
<Order id="123">
 <Product> 
       <Sku>110313</Sku>
       <Name>Name1</Name> 
       <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
    </Product> 
    <Product> 
       <Sku>112985</Sku> 
       <Name>Name2</Name> 
       <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
   </Product>
   </Order>
```

Now if i provide input as 110313 output should be First Product Node

I have tried so far

```
XmlNode orderNode = orderDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Order[@Id='" + textBox1.Text + "']");

XmlNode skuNode = orderNode.SelectSingleNode("/Product/Sku[text()='" + txt_barcode.Text + "']");
```

But its showing SKU as null. I have passed correct input.

Any Help

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector:

```
/Order/Product[Sku=110313]

XmlNode skuNode = orderNode.SelectSingleNode(/Order/Product[Sku=" + txt_barcode.Text + "]");
```